# How can I prevent, in Angular, two incompatible directives to be assigned to the same element?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have to similar directives that shouldn't be added to the same HTML element to avoid weird behaviour.

Is there any standard way to establish to directives as incompatible or to check whether these to directives are assigned to the same element and throw an error or a warning?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that with a custom rule in linter such as eslint. Configure it as error and the linting will fail when the rule is met. I believe it's a better approach than trying to detect it in the code of the directives themselves during runtime. There are plenty of resources discussing custom eslint rules such as https://flexport.engineering/writing-custom-lint-rules-for-your-picky-developers-67732afa1803